# Magento 2 - Serverside Validation

Tags: magento2, php, validation, zend

In magento 1 we could use Zend to validate input values, for example check if the value is an e-mail or an integer.

Example

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) { ... }
```

How does it work in Magento 2?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

In your Magento 2 Installation, take a look at the Validator located in  `/vendor/magento/framework/validator`.

This is the README.md:

```
This library extends Zend Framework's validator library and is used for validating input data in forms. 
Implements an XML-configuration that allows defining validation constraints in a declarative way.
```